# From python, can we track module-level assignments before (other) user code executes?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I'm working on a tool that would benefit from the ability to track all references to a given object from within python.

Specifically, I'd like to make a test doubles system that could replace all module-level attributes of a given type.  For example, assume the following code is in module c:

```
from a import b
```

If a is a module, b is a reference to the object named a.b, but it is a *separate* reference.  If my test double system later replaces a.b, c.b will still refer to the original object.

I would like to have my tool track all assignments of a.b to aliases, but module-level aliasing would go a long way toward my goal.

Metaphorically, what I'd like is to override `Module.__setattribute__`:

```
def __setattribute__(self, name, value):
    if isinstance(value, interesting_types):
        # remember this use of the interesting object and call super for normal processing.
```

Assume that I can get my code loaded before modules which might be tracked can be loaded.

Comment: It occurred to me that I might be able to use an importer to do the trick - because once imported (by the normal methods), I could inspect the returned object's attributes and track there. I'll look closer at this approach.

Comment: I'm probably missing something ... `from a import b` creates a new `b` in the current scope that's distinct from `a.b`. If you assign a value to `b`, it doesn't change the value of `a.b`. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am interested in pointing all references to the original b to another implementation of b.  Specifically, I'm trying to build a test doubles system that allows you to replace all references to the normal implementation with a spy, fake, stub, or mock.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing may work for you. First, some code:

*a.py*

```
b = 42
# other module definitions
```

*fakery.py*

```
class Fakery(object):
    def __init__(self, mod):
        self.module = __import__(mod)
        import sys
        sys.modules[self.module.__name__] = self

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print "__getattr__ called with '%s'" % name
        result = getattr(self.module, name)
        if name == 'b':
            result += 1
        return result
```

*Example*

```
>>> import fakery
>>> fakery.Fakery('a')
<fakery.Fakery object at 0x109007110>
>>> from a import b
__getattr__ called with '__path__'
__getattr__ called with 'b'
>>> print b
43
>>> import a
>>> print a
<fakery.Fakery object at 0x109007110>
```

All you would have to do is modify the `Fakery` class to do whatever it is that you want to do. In this case, I'm just adding 1 to `a`'s `b`.

I hope it's clear how this works, but here's a quick explanation.

When a module is imported, a record of it gets stuffed into `sys.modules`. When you instantiate a `Fakery` object, what it does is import a module by name (using [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)), and then replaces that module's entry in `sys.modules` with itself.

Python only imports modules once, storing the imported module in `sys.modules`. Every import after the first returns the entry in sys.modules. The `Fakery` object inserts *itself* into `sys.modules['a']`, taking the place of the real module. All subsequent `import a` or `from a import <whatever>` statements are now directed to an instance of `Fakery`. Since it's just a class, you can do all kinds of crazy stuff using magic methods or metaprogramming.

`__getattr__` is convenient because it gets called when a requested attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Seth, it feels a bit dirty - I'm a little worried about shadowing the normal module without inheriting from it - but I agree this might work well enough.  I'll accept the answer after I have some time to poke at it.